# Acumatica GetList error: Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error: Attributes.AttributeID

Tags: acumatica

Developer's version of Acumatica 2020R1 is installed locally. Data for sample tenant MyTenant from training for I-300 were loaded, and WSDL connection established.

DefaultSoapClient is created fine.

However, attempts to export any data by using Getlist cause errors:

```
       using (Default.DefaultSoapClient soapClient =
             new Default.DefaultSoapClient())
        {
            //Sign in to Acumatica ERP
            soapClient.Login
            (
                "Admin",
                "*",
                "MyTenant",
                "Yogifon",
                null
            );

            try
            {
                //Retrieving the list of customers with contacts
                //InitialDataRetrieval.RetrieveListOfCustomers(soapClient);
                //Retrieving the list of stock items modified within the past day
                // RetrievalOfDelta.ExportStockItems(soapClient);
                RetrievalOfDelta.ExportItemClass(soapClient);
            }

    public static void ExportItemClass(DefaultSoapClient soapClient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieving the list of item classes...");
        ItemClass ItemClassToBeFound = new ItemClass
        {
            ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All,
        };
        Entity[] ItemClasses = soapClient.GetList(ItemClassToBeFound);

        string lcItemType = "", lcValuationMethod = "";
        int lnCustomFieldsCount;

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("ItemClass.csv"))
        {
            //Write the values for each item
            foreach (ItemClass loItemClass in ItemClasses)
            {
                file.WriteLine(loItemClass.Note);
            }
        }
```

The Acumatica instance was modified by adding a custom field to Stock Items using DAC, and by adding several Attributes to Customer and Stock Items.

Interesting enough, this code used to work until something broke it.

What is wrong here?

Thank you.
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

In the request you have the following line: `ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All`
That means that you try to retrieve all linked/detail entities of the object. Unfortunately, some object are not optimized enough to not affect query performance in GetList scenarios. 
So, you have to options:

1. Replace ReturnBehavior=All by explicitly specifying linked/detail entities that you want to retrieve and not include Attributes into the list.
2. Retrieve StockItem with attributes one by one using Get operation instead of GetList.

P.S. The problem with attributes will most likely be fixed in the next version of API endpoint.

Edit:

Code sample for Get:

```
public static void ExportItemClass(DefaultSoapClient soapClient)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Retrieving the list of item classes...");
    ItemClass ItemClassToBeFound = new ItemClass
    {
        ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.Default //retrieve only default fields (without attributes and other linked/detailed entities)
    };
    Entity[] ItemClasses = soapClient.GetList(ItemClassToBeFound);

   foreach(var entity in ItemClasses)
   {
       ItemClass itemClass= entity  as ItemClass;
       ItemClass.ReturnBehavior=ReturnBehavior.All;
       // retrieve each ItemClass with all the details/linked entities individually
       ItemClass retrievedItemCLass = soapClient.Get(itemClass);

   }
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitrii. So, that were Attributes that I created on customers and items that killed the previous export. Could you please provide a code sample using Get to export entities with attributes?

Comment: Customer CustomerToBeFound = new Customer
{
ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.Default,
};

Entity[] Customers = soapClient.GetList(CustomerToBeFound);

foreach (var entity in Customers)
{
   Customer loCustomer = entity as Customer;
   loCustomer.ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All;
Customer retrievedCustomer = soapClient.Get(loCustomer);
}
On the last line, compiler say cannot convert entity to Customer.

Comment: For the previous comment: ItemClass retrievedItemCLass = (entity)soapClient.Get(itemClass); does the trick.                                                           It looks, like the second loop returns all fields that entity already has, and is there just to get Attributes. Is it possible to set ItemClass.ReturnBehavior=ReturnBehavior.Specified; and list just field Attributes to return?